# Hibernate envers and ElementCollection

Tags: java, hibernate-envers

I have a simple program with a Resource and List of ItemSelection like this

```
@Audited
@Table(name = "resource_item")
public class Resource {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
  private Long id;

  private String nom;

  @ElementCollection(targetClass = ItemSelection.class)
  @CollectionTable(name = "item_selection", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "resource_id"))
  @OrderColumn(name = "list_order")
  private final List<ItemSelection> itemSelections = new ArrayList<>();
  ...
  ...
```

```
@Embeddable
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class ItemSelection {

  //@Column(name = "hierarchy_code", nullable = false)
  private String hierarchyCode;
  //@Column(name = "hierarchy_level", nullable = false)
  private int hierarchyLevel;
  //@Column(name = "hierarchy_value_code", nullable = false)
  private String hierarchyValueCode;

  ...
  ...
```

When i m adding resource with 3 elements in itemSelections, hibernate envers log correctly:

```
localhost sa@envers=# select * from item_selection_aud ;
 rev | revtype | resource_id | list_order | hierarchy_value_code | hierarchy_code | hierarchy_level 
-----+---------+-------------+------------+----------------------+----------------+-----------------
   2 |       0 |           1 |          1 | hvalueCode3          | hcode3         |               3
   2 |       0 |           1 |          0 | hvalueCode1          | hcode1         |               1
   2 |       0 |           1 |          2 | hvalueCode2          | hcode2         |               2
(3 rows)
```

when i m updating one line in item_selection, i only see one update in sql but hibernate envers log this:

```
localhost sa@envers=# select * from item_selection_aud ;
 rev | revtype | resource_id | list_order | hierarchy_value_code | hierarchy_code | hierarchy_level 
-----+---------+-------------+------------+----------------------+----------------+-----------------
   2 |       0 |           1 |          1 | hvalueCode3          | hcode3         |               3
   2 |       0 |           1 |          0 | hvalueCode1          | hcode1         |               1
   2 |       0 |           1 |          2 | hvalueCode2          | hcode2         |               2
   3 |       0 |           1 |          0 | hvalueCode1          | CODE           |               1
   3 |       2 |           1 |          0 | hvalueCode1          | hcode1         |               1
(5 rows)
```

as you can see, i have a revtype 2 and 0 for the modified line instead of revtype 1 for an update.

I'have try to use @Column(name = "hierarchy_code", nullable = false) but nothing change.

For now my only solution is to transform @ElementCollection into @OneToMany, but I have many @ElementCollection in my application so too many refactoring...

Did I miss something in the configuration? I am using DefaultAuditStrategy, same behavior with ValidityAuditStrategy that only add revend column. Hibernate-envers 5.6.12-Final

Comment: Hi @Mancaux Pierre-Alexandre, did you find any solution of this problem?

Comment: No i have open a jira directly on hibernate…i m waiting…